# Rename dynamic references in Python files using VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, refactoring, rename

Is there a way to rename dynamic references when refactoring Python files in VS Code? E.g., consider the following example:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x


def test(cls):
    print(cls.x)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test(Test(21))
```

In PyCharm, using "refactor -> rename" (Shift + F6) to rename the `Test` class attribute `x` to `y` will automatically detect that `x` is dynamically referenced in `test` and also refactor `print(cls.x)` to `print(cls.y)`.

On the other hand, using "rename symbol" (F2) in VS Code to do the same refactoring will not affect any dynamic references, resulting in broken code.

Is there a way to replicate the PyCharm renaming behavior in VS Code?

(Using "Change all occurences" (Ctrl + F2) renames *all* occurrence of `x`, resulting in far too many renames.)

---

Note: It's possible to get VS Code to include `cls.x` in the refactoring by using type hints:

```
def test(cls: Test):
    print(cls.x)
```

But for large projects it's not always feasible to add type hints everywhere. So having a way for the editor to show me all dynamic references and offer to include them in the refactoring would be convenient.

Comment: the type of `cls` in `test` is not confined to `Test` so `x` should not be renamed

Comment: hover over `cls` and see what VSC assumes the type of `cls`  is, VSC deduces return types not argument types, nothing prevents you from using PyCharm if you like that behavior, or write your own refactor for VSC to do the same

Comment: `test` should operate on an **interface** not a class

Comment: @rioV8 note that `cls` is a class instance not a class. You are right that based on a static analysis alone, there is no way to infer that `cls` will be an instance of `Test`. My question is about whether there is a way for VS Code to understand  dynamic references like PyCharm does. In this example, this would amount to understanding that in the last line `test` is called with an instance of `Test` as an argument.

Comment: BTW, PyCharm also doesn't automatically rename all dynamic references but rather opens a sophisticated preview dialog where it shows all detected dynamic references and asks whether to include them in the rename or not

Comment: other languages force you to `type` everything, so why not do it in Python too

Comment: I am not trying to have a discussion on type hinting. For many one appeal of Python is that type hints are mostly optional. I am also not saying that VS Code should always infer argument types dynamically. I am simply asking whether there is some (optional) way in VS Code to also consider dynamic references when refactoring.

Comment: `cls` is not a class object but a class instance, `def test(cls)` is confusing

Comment: If you feel that the current rename function cannot meet your needs, you can submit a report request enhancement on [github](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/new/choose).